# Change pivot table layout into "more columns"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, powerpivot

When I create a pivot table in excel 2010 my table looks like that:

[image]

Any suggestions how to get this extra colume filled up with the names within a pivot table?

Or do I need to use power pivot? How could I do it there?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click inside the Pivot Table, then on the PivotTable Tools > Design ribbon > Report Layout. Here, select "Show in Tabular Form" and also select "Repeat all item Labels".

This command is available in Excel 2010 and above.

[image]